# Creating emulator for Zebra mobile computers- Handheld device

Tags: android, android-emulator, barcode-scanner, terminal-emulator

I am creating an app for Zebra mobile computer TC25/TC20 for scanning barcodes. 
For this after installing Emdk for Zebra I am able to see the EMDK api, but system image is not available to create Emulator.

Can anyone please help me to get these system image file for Zebra devices.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The images are not available for any of the Zebra mobile computers and you need to develop on a physical device, at least when you come to integrate with the EMDK library.  Some people develop their applications to run on both Zebra & non-Zebra devices which would allow you to develop as much as possible on an emulator and move to a physical device only when you work on scanner integration (one example of doing something similar is my app at https://github.com/darryncampbell/WakeLock_WifiLock_Exerciser)

Comment: So we always need a physical device to test my code which handles scanning events as no emulators are available?

Comment: If you are using the EMDK scanning library then that is correct, yes.  Zebra do offer an alternative way to scan barcodes known as 'DataWedge' which is a service resident on the device that will deliver scanned barcodes as Android Intents.  If an application was solely making use of the DataWedge service it could be tested on an emulator by mocking the intents via adb.  If you are interested in learning more about that then let me know.

Comment: Thanks @darryn, Yes I want to know how can we scan barcodes using datawage, help please

Comment: DataWedge is a service resident on all Zebra mobile computers, on Android it can be configured to send intents when barcodes are scanned.  I created a tutorial at http://www.darryncampbell.co.uk/2017/12/13/tutorial-scan-with-datawedge-intent-output-on-zebra-devices/ which shows how to do this in a native Android app.  You can simulate a scan by using the following command: `adb shell am broadcast -a com.dwexample.ACTION -e com.symbol.datawedge.data_string 0123456789 -e com.symbol.datawedge.source scanner -e com.symbol.datawedge.label_type EAN13`

Comment: Thanks, let me try it

Comment: @DarrynCampbell your answer is great! greatly appreciate your help!!

Comment: We chose a different approach to testing: we implemented a separate intent service  into our application which processes intents raised via adb. That way we can feed barcode scan events into both an emulated and a physical device likewise. This is extremely handy for regression testing for example: we operate a form of 20 physical devices orchestrated by appium which is integrated in our deployment pipeline. That allows us to run regression tests feeding the barcode scan events via adb.

Comment: @arkascha I did something similar for another customer a while back (3 years) - the source code is released under MIT at https://github.com/darryncampbell/GenericScanWedge if anybody reading this finds it useful.